# axios random url picking

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I just wonder how to pick random URLs to performed an axios post request.

I have three servers I want to pick randomly from

```
let one = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/middle/server_js/"
let two = "http://127.0.0.1:8001/middle/server_js/"
let three = "http://127.0.0.1:8002/middle/server_js/"
```

currently is using only one:

```
let req = await axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/middle/server_js/", body, {
```

I just want to choose random port from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of a solution via an array

```
// Defining an array
var arr = ['adress1', 'adress2', 'adress3'];

// Getting a random array key
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

alert(arr[rand]); // "adress2" for example
```

Comment: this will stick with one server, am pushing multi workers, so i want each worker choose randomly between those servers.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for not using an array, and then using a random key to select a random server. In any case, you will have to work either with arrays or with